# Grouping unique column values to sum of each unique value in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

I am trying to take a pandas dataframe and group it based on two columns to get the sum for each unique combination in the corresponding values column.

The Dataframe looks like this:

```
Charge Code  Billing Number  Amount
1250-001        500120        5000
1250-001        500120       -5000
1250-001        500220         300
1250-001        520320         400
1136-001        360220         700
1136-001        360220        -100
1207-001        070420         100
1207-001        070420         200
1207-001        070420         300
1207-001        070320         400
1090-001        900220         500
```

I would like to group the dataframe by the Charge code and Billing Number columns to get the sum of the values in the Amount column. If the sum ends up being zero, it should not be included in the dataframe.

The desired dataframe would look like the following:

```
 Charge Code  Billing Number  Amount
  1250-001      500220         300
  1250-001      520320         400
  1136-001      360220         600
  1207-001      070420         600
  1207-001      070320         400
  1090-001      900220         500
```

I am assuming it should look something like:

```
df_Paid.groupby(level=0)['Charge Code','Billing Number'].sum()
```

Using the solution:

```
df_Paid.groupby(['Charge Code','Billing Number'])['Amount'].sum().replace(0, np.nan).dropna()
```

returns:

```
Charge Code  Billing Number  Amount
  1250-001      500220         300
                520320         400
  1136-001      360220         600
  1207-001      070420         600
                070320         400
  1090-001      900220         500
```

which gives me the following error when I attempt to move it to google sheets using google api:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

due to the empty Charge code lines in the Charge code colum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the 0 by NaN and then drop the NaN values:

```
df_Paid.groupby(['Charge Code','Billing Number'])['Amount'].sum().replace(0, np.nan).dropna().reset_index()
```

Comment: This technically works; however, I need it to keep the Charge code next to the billing number for each billing number. I added what was returned to the question above. This would work, but I am moving this data to a google sheet using google API and it won't do it with the empty Charge Code lines.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can `agg` then loc the `values != 0` :

```
df_temp = df_Paid['Charge Code','Billing Number'].agg({'Amount': 'sum'}).reset_index()
df_Paid = df_temp.loc[df_temp['Amount'] != 0]
```